# Matching string across multiple regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, postgresql

I have a postgresql database with table that contains about 50 million entries of strings that are addresses. Example of strings are

```
NIAID, Opportunist Infect Res Branch, Treatment Res Programs, Div Aids, Bethesda, MD USA
PRINCETON UNIV,DEPT PSYCHOL,PRINCETON,NJ 08544
```

etc.

Now I have to check if an address matches any of a list of about 30,000 regular expressions. I also need to know which regular expression is matched. Examples of regular expressions are

```
%umass mem med ctr worcester%worcester%ma%
%darnnouth%
```

This is of course in the 'LIKE' format for postgres. Since regex matching cannot take advantage of indexing (not a lot anyway, I have already indexed the field varchar_pattern_ops), the total running time of this operation will be about 30000x50 million.

I can also use python to do regex matching if there exists any python library that will help me quicken the process.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: 30,000 regular expressions: that's quite a lot, you might want to compile them first if this is going to be repeated for several queries.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'compile'? Querying postgresql database does not require compiling afaik. And its not going to be repeated. This is a one time operation.

Comment: Not sure you are correct about postgres being able to use indexes with queries like that. If you have `%` at the start of an expression then it is still going to cause a seq scan. Make sure you check `EXPLAIN`

Comment: @ChrisFarmiloe There is a `pg_trgm` module which can use index for expresions starting with `%`

Comment: @amhrpi see http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
CREATE TABLE regex (
     regex text primary key
);

SELECT * FROM my_table
  JOIN regex ON mytextfield like regex;
```

Comment: This seems like the fastest option as it uses `JOIN` to carry out the regex matching. There probably isn't anyway way to speed this up further. Thanks.